# Print strings in order with dynamic arrays

Tags: c, sorting, memory-management

I accomplished the following task to practice allocating on the heap.

- reading words from stdin
- sorting them in lexicographical order
- printing the sorted words to stdout

To accomplish this is allocate the size of each word and the count of words.

I would like to hear any suggestions for improvements. Is there maybe an easier way to sort the words?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct Word {
    char* signs;    // pointer to a word
    int sz;
    int capacity;
};

// allocates factor 2 of the current capacity
void reserve_space_for_letter(char **c, int *capacity) 
{
    if (*capacity == 0) {   // allocate the first time
        *capacity = 1;
        *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * ((*capacity)));
    }
    else {
        *capacity *= 2;     // double the new capacity
        *c = realloc(*c, sizeof(char) * (*capacity));
    }
}

void reserve_space_for_words(struct Word** w, int *capacity) 
{
    if (*capacity == 0) {   // allocate the first time
        *capacity = 1;
        *w = malloc(sizeof(struct Word) * ((*capacity)));
    }
    else {
        *capacity *= 2;     // double the new capacity
        *w = realloc(*w, sizeof(struct Word) * (*capacity));
    }
}

void print_words(struct Word* words,int sz) 
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        printf("%s ", words[i].signs);
    }
}

int cmp(void const *lhs, void const *rhs) {
    struct Word left = *(const struct Word *)lhs;
    struct Word right = *(const struct Word *)rhs;

    return strcmp(left.signs, right.signs);
}

void deallocate_words(struct Word* words, int sz)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        free(words[i].signs);
    }
    free(words);
}


int main()
{
    struct Word* words;     // Pointer to several words
    int sz = 0;
    int capacity = 0;

    int ch=0;
    bool in_word = true;

    reserve_space_for_words(&words, &capacity); // reserve space for first word
    ++sz;
    words[sz - 1].capacity = 0;
    words[sz - 1].sz = 0;

    while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {

        if (words[sz - 1].sz == words[sz - 1].capacity) {       // if current letter sz = capacity
            reserve_space_for_letter(&words[sz - 1].signs, &words[sz - 1].capacity);
        }

        if (!isalnum(ch) && in_word) {      // end of current word;
            words[sz - 1].signs[words[sz - 1].sz] = '\0';
            in_word = false;
            continue;
        }
        else if (!isalnum(ch) && !in_word) {        // not in a word so dont bother doing sth
            continue;
        }
        else if (isalnum(ch) && !in_word) {     // the next word is reached
            in_word = true;

            if (sz == capacity) {       // maximum size of words reached
                reserve_space_for_words(&words, &capacity); // reserve space for first word
            }
            ++sz;       // iterate to the new word
            words[sz - 1].capacity = 0;
            words[sz - 1].sz = 0;

            reserve_space_for_letter(&words[sz - 1].signs, &words[sz - 1].capacity);
        }

        words[sz - 1].signs[words[sz - 1].sz] = ch;    // append the sign in the array
        ++words[sz - 1].sz;
    }
    qsort(words, sz, sizeof(struct Word), cmp);
    print_words(words, sz);
    deallocate_words(words, sz);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: one thing i found myself i use `strcmp` but i didnt included `#include <string.h>` the c compiler of visual studio 2017 didnt cared. i turned it to cpp and got more warnings. is it a good practice to do (just for debug turn to c++) that because c++ catches more errors even in c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bug

If the last word is followed by `EOF`, then a *null character* is not append nor space made for it. `words[sz - 1]` will not be a *string* and `strcmp()` is *undefined behavior*.

**Simplify `main()`**

Suggest a re-write of the `main()` loop, (which should be in a helper function).

```
// while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
int ch = ' '; // dummy non-isalnum character
while (ch != EOF) {
  while (!isalnum(ch)) && ch != EOF) {
    ch = getc(stdin);
  } 
  if (ch == EOF) break;

  // Beginning of new word found, allocate for it.
  new_word(...);
  while (isalnum(ch))) {
    append_letter(ch, ...);
    ch = getc(stdin);
  }
  append_letter('\0', ...);
}
```

Simplifications possible if your care to use `do {} while` loops.

```
do {
  do {
     ch = getc(stdin);
   } while (!isalnum(ch)) && ch != EOF);
   if (ch == EOF) break;

   // Beginning of new word found, allocate for it.
   new_word(...);
   do {
     append_letter(ch, ...);
     ch = getc(stdin);
   } while (isalnum(ch));
   append_letter('\0', ...);
} while (ch != EOF);
```

`main()` splits  out the *words* as `words , sz, capacity` and has a lot of code for reading.  It has simple calls for sorting and printing.  I'd expect a `main()` more along this:

```
int main(void) {
  Words word_list = { 0 };
  if (Words_Read(&word_list)) {
    Words_Sort(&word_list);
    Words_Print(&word_list);
  }
  Words_Free(&word_list);
}
```

**`isalpha()` vs. `isalnum()`**

Unclear why code accepts digits for "words".  I'd expect `isalpha()` or at least a comment about digits in words.

**sizeof type vs. sizeof object**

Using the size of the object rather than the size of the type is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// *w = malloc(sizeof(struct Word) * ((*capacity)));
*w = malloc(sizeof **w * (*capacity));

// *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * ((*capacity)));
*c = malloc(sizeof **c * (*capacity));

// qsort(words, sz, sizeof(struct Word), cmp);
qsort(words, sz, sizeof words[0], cmp);
```

**No need to copy the whole structure**

```
// struct Word left = *(const struct Word *)lhs;
const char *left = ((const struct Word *)lhs)->signs;
...
// return strcmp(left.signs, right.signs);
return strcmp(left, right);
```

Comment: thanks for the effort of revieing. I found maybe one issue. `qsort(words, sz, sizeof sz[0], cmp);` doesnt seem to be a valid expression

Comment: it markes the '0' and gives `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0142 expression must have pointer-to-object type`

Comment: yes now it works as intended

Answer (score 4):

When allocating an array to hold arbitrary numbers of things, consider using `calloc` and `reallocarray` (`reallocarray` is not standard C, but there isn't a standard analog to `calloc`).

The reason is that `calloc` will fail if you try to allocate more memory than `size_t` can hold. If, for example on a 32-bit system, you decide you want to allocate 500 million of some struct, you could do this:

```
typedef struct { char a; } little_struct_t;
...
ptr = malloc(500000000 * sizeof(little_struct_t));
```

and it might work. But later, when you decide that your struct actually needs more stuff, you'll end up with something like this:

```
typedef struct { char a; int b; bool c } little_struct_t;
...
ptr = malloc(500000000 * sizeof(little_struct_t));
```

and boom, you've just caused a multiplication overflow without thinking about it. If instead you had used `calloc`, you'd either see the error when you checked that `ptr` was not `NULL` (see my next comment) or a happy segfault when you try to dereference `ptr`. Instead, now you have a 1705032704-byte (`(sizeof(little_struct_t) * half a billion) & 0xffffffff)`) chunk of memory, and if you're lucky you'll get a segfault when you write off the end of it. If you're not lucky, you'll corrupt a bunch of other memory before your program crashes.

My second comment is that you should always *always* check the return value of `malloc`. If it's not `NULL`, no harm done. If it is, either you want to crash *right now* or you want to take a different path. Whatever happens, you don't want your program to happily keep chugging along as though nothing's wrong.

Third, and this isn't super relevant to your example (though I would apply it in `deallocate_words` after the `free` call inside the loop), but it's good practice to null out your pointers after you free them. I think I've spent too many words already, so I'll just say that it will simplify debugging and get rid of double free issues in the future.

Comment: thank you very much for youre review. So in conclusion its always better to use `calloc` for user defined data structures? when to use `malloc` then?

Comment: If you're only allocating space for 1 instance of a struct, not an array of them, and you don't care about having your memory zeroed out, use `malloc`. In general, if you're multiplying inside the `malloc` call, consider using `calloc`.

Comment: i tryed to find the reallocarray function but i couldnt find a source for it. is it available already in visual studio 2017?

Comment: Sorry, `reallocarray` is a Linux/glibc thing. I don't know about windows libraries.

Answer (score 3):

- Put the logic where it belongs. The main loop should only adds characters to the word, while `Word` shall manage itself, e.g.:

  ```
  if (isalnum(ch)) {
      add_character(word, ch);
  }
  ```

  A possible implementation would be

  ```
  add_character(struct Word * word, char ch) {
      if (word->size == word->capacity) {
          expand_capacity(word);
      }
      word->signs[word->size++] = ch;
  }
  ```

  The same applies to the list of words.

  As a side note, they logic of `reserve_space_for_letter` and `reserve_space_for_words` is identical, and it may be worthy of effort to unify expansion mechanism along the lines of

  ```
  void * expand_array(void * array, size_t capacity, size_t element_size);
  ```
- The main logic could be streamlined:

  ```
  do {
      struct Word * word = get_empty_word_from_list(....);

      while (ch = getchar() && isalnum(ch) {
          add_character(word, ch);
      }
      add_character(word, '\0');

      while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && !isalnum(ch)) {
          ;
      }
  } while (ch != EOF);
  ```

  Of course both inner loops would benefit if factored out into functions, say `read_word` and `skip_non_word`.

Comment: 1) The "streamlined" version looks like it loses letters.  When `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && !isalnum(ch))` stops due to a letter like  `'e'`, that `'e'` is lost.  Perhaps `unget()` or something to fix?  2) if 1st charter is a non-alnum, code will make word `""`.  Yet you are very correct that the `main()` loop needs improvement.

Comment: @chux Agreed. It was somewhat half baked. I should be clear that it is not a working code (CR is not about that) but a guideline.

Comment: i tryed the generalisation to `expand array` but is it possible? it always gives a corrput heap with realloc. malloc seems to kinda work. I do this: Giving the array to the function `word_list->words = (struct Word*) expand_array(&word_list->words, &word_list->capacity, sizeof(struct Word));`   then malloc and looks like this: `array = malloc(element_size * (*capacity));` `array = realloc(array, element_size * (*capacity));` I changed the parameter capacity to a pointer to be able to return it by reference.